# Getting Junk characters while trying to print the file contents using Java

Tags: java, readfile

I am reading a file's contents and trying to print the contents using java. But it prints junk characters along with the file content.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {

    public String readFile(String filePath){

        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
        File file = new File(filePath);


        try{
            String lines = null;
            FileReader fileReader1 = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fileReader1);

            while((lines = buffer.readLine())!=null){
                contents.append(lines);

            }
            buffer.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                System.out.println("File not found.");
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Exception ocurred.");
        }
        return contents.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
        String lines = rf.readFile("C:\\Data\\FaultDn.txt");

        System.out.println("Original file contents: " + lines);


    }
}
```

The file contents are:

```
partner.cisco.com:org-root/mac-pool-QA_MAC_Pool_5-Sep-2012_12:00
```

The output is:

```
"Original file contents: ÿþp ..." and then junk characters after every letter.
```

Can you please point me to what I am missing in this code?

Comment: `readLine` strips the end-of-line character(s), so you need `.append(System.getProperty("file.separator"))`. The rest seems okay, so maybe FaultDn.txt has hidden rubbish. Look at the file size, or try a different text.

Comment: It seems you're trying to show an image that you haven't uploaded.

Comment: Are you sure, you are getting the given output  after running this program only?

Comment: Does C:\Share\Output.jpg mean anything to you? I am thinking maybe you are looking at a version of the file different than the one your program has access to. Is this file C:\\Data\\FaultDn.txt modifiable between the time you look at it and the time you read it from the program?

Comment: I am trying to attach an image file to show the output but I am unable to do that. The output that I get is "Original file contents: ÿþp ..." and then junk characters after every letter.

Comment: As @Joop Eggen rightly pointed, FaultDn.txt has hidden rubbish. This file is generated as a result of a powershell script. I have tried the program with another file and it seems to work perfectly fine except that "null" is appended at the end of the file contents. Is there a way I can eliminate this hidden rubbish? I need to read the file generated out of powershell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I have corrected my powershell script by adding ASCII encoding as follows:

```
Out-File -Encoding ASCII
```

and I have used

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

This resolves the issue and prints the file contents as it is (including new lines)

Answer (score 0):

The only explanations I can think of are:

- you are reading a different file to the one you think you are reading, or
- the program you are executing doesn't match the source code above; e.g. you are executing an old version of the class file.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried you'r code. It is working correctly. but I used Ubuntu so I only changed you file path. so sometimes error occurred in you'r file path or in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is misleading as most of us understood that the output your program is generating is

> `![Alt Output](C:\Share\Output.jpg)`

If the what you are reading contains junk characters then it is most likely an encoding issue. How was the original file generated?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you all. But I did not get how to add an image file here. As @Joop Eggen rightly pointed, FaultDn.txt has hidden rubbish. This file is generated as a result of a powershell script. I have tried the program with another file and it seems to work perfectly fine except that "null" is appended at the end of the file contents. Is there a way I can eliminate this hidden rubbish? I need to read the file generated out of powershell script.

Comment: Any suggestions? Please help!